# Passing values from directive to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is my html template:

```
<div ng-app="dr" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <test color1="color1" data-method="ctrlFn(msg)"></test>    
</div>
```

Below is my code:

```
var app = angular.module('dr', []);

app.controller("testCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.ctrlFn = function(arg) {        
        alert(arg);
    }

});
app.directive('test', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            fromDirectiveFn: '&method'
        },
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            //Way One
            scope.hello = "some message";
            scope.fromDirectiveFn(scope.hello);
        }
    }
});

<div ng-app="dr" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <test color1="color1" data-method="ctrlFn(msg)"></test>    
</div>
```

Why am i getting "**undefined**" instead of "**some message**"

Below is a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/j2K7N/27/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, however you had several issues here:

```
<test color1="color1" data-method="ctrlFn(msg)"></test>
```

Here you pass the `ctrlFn()` function from your controller, which takes one undefined argument `msg`, that causes the alert message with "undefined" text. I suggest to modify the HTML code to this:

```
<test color1="color1" data-method="ctrlFn"></test>
```

Note that I pass the `ctrlFn` as a variable, not function.

In your directive code, I changed the scope binding to `=` to make sure that the `ctrlFn` will point to your controller function. This also sets up a two-way binding between the directive's scope and the controller (parent) scope. Then the whole JS code of the directive will look like this:

```
app.directive('test', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            fromDirectiveFn: '=method'
        },
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            //Way One
            scope.hello = "some message";
            scope.fromDirectiveFn(scope.hello);
        }
    }
});
```

Just replacing the `&` to `=`. Working fork: http://jsfiddle.net/L8masomq/

Answer (score 2):

its bit of a quirk... read more about it [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-3-isolate-scope-and-function-parameters)

what you need to do is - change below

```
scope.fromDirectiveFn(scope.hello);
```

to

```
 scope.fromDirectiveFn({'msg' : scope.hello});
```

the variable names should be same in caller & callee

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the code is correct. But, the value of msg which is getting undefined. Thus, you ctrlFn(msg) is returning as undefined.
adding the 'msg' property and assigning the scope.hello will resolve the problem. Check the improved [Jsfiddle][1] here.

```
scope.fromDirectiveFn({'msg': scope.hello});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/imsabmaverick81/j2K7N/215/