# How to load json data into handsontable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, handsontable

I am using sheetJs to get json data from csv/xls file in a directive.

```
myApp.directive("fileRead", [function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            data: '='
        },
        link: function ($scope, $elm, $attrs) {
            $elm.on('change', function (changeEvent) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (evt) {
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        var data = evt.target.result;

                        var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'binary'});

                        var headerNames = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(
                                workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]],
                                {header: 1}
                        )[0];

                        console.log("headerNames: ", headerNames);

                        var data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]]);

                        console.log("sheet2Json: " , data);

                        $scope.columnDefs = [];
                        headerNames.forEach(function (h) {
                            $scope.columnDefs.push({field: h});
                        });

                        $scope.data = data;
                        console.log("file 4: " , data);                             

                        $elm.val(null);
                    });
                };

                reader.readAsBinaryString(changeEvent.target.files[0]);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

The data retrieved as json is in `$scope.data = data;` object. I have my sample handsontable in a separate js file like this:

```
var myData = [
    ["KK", 1234567890, "k.k999@gmail.com", "kvp@gmail.com"],
    ["KK", 1234567890, "k.k999@gmail.com", "kvp@gmail.com"],
    ["KK", 1234567890, "k.k999@gmail.com", "kvp@gmail.com"],
],
        container = document.querySelector('#exampleGrid');

var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: myData,
    startRows: 5,
    startCols: 5,
    minSpareCols: 0,
    //always keep at least 1 spare row at the right
    minSpareRows: 0,
    //always keep at least 1 spare row at the bottom,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: ['Name', 'Mobile number', 'Sender Email', 'Receiver Email'],
    contextMenu: true,
    width: 120,
    wordWrap: true
});
```

Looking at the Handsontable documentation I see a method to load json data:

```
 hot.loadData(data.data);
```

Now how I do load the scope.data(jsondata) into the above method which is in a separate js file. Do I have to create a controller and pass the data to controllers scope?

Html:

```
<div class="top-big-link">
    <file-read>
        <input id="csvFile" type="file" name="image" accept=".xls, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" title=" "/>
        <button id="csvFileImport" class="ImportFromExcelButton"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"> </i> Import from Excel</button>
    </file-read>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('csvFileImport').addEventListener('click', function () {
            document.getElementById('csvFile').click();

        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is right way of doing it but it worked for me.

Got my solution working from this link: [Passing values from directive to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069816/passing-values-from-directive-to-controller)

Thanks to @Thomas Weglinski

Solution:

Changed my directive to two-way binding.

```
myApp.directive("fileRead", [function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            fromDirectiveFn: '=method'
        },
    },

    function link(scope, element, attrs){

        $scope.data = data; //Json data reecieved from csv/xls file
        $scope.fromDirectiveFn($scope.data);
    }
}
```

And change my HTML to the following:

```
<file-read method="loadJson">
    <input id="csvFile" type="file" name="image" accept=".xls, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" title=" "/>
    <button id="csvFileImport" class="ImportFromExcelButton"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"> </i> Import from Excel</button>
</file-read>
```

This line `method="loadJson` calls the function inside controller and passes the data.

Answer (score 0):

// For Angular

// Inside component.html

```
<hot-table [settings]="tableSettings" [data]="dataset" licenseKey= 'non-commercial-and-evaluation'></hot-table>
```

// Inside component.ts

```
tableSettings: any = {
    
    rowHeaders: true,
    // colHeaders: true,
    viewportColumnRenderingOffset: 27,
    viewportRowRenderingOffset: "auto",
    // colWidths: 150,
    // height: 500,
    // allowInsertColumn: false,
    // allowInsertRow: false,
    // allowRemoveColumn: false,
    // allowRemoveRow: false,
    // autoWrapRow: false,
    // autoWrapCol: false,
    // stretchH: "all",
    width: 3000,
    // autoWrapRow: true,
    //height: 487,
    // maxRows: 22,
    // manualRowResize: true,
    // manualColumnResize: true,
    // rowHeaders: true,
    
    colHeaders: [
      "Invoice_No",
      "Product_Description",
      "Receiver_Contact_Person_Name",
      "Receiver_Contact_Number",
      "Dropoff_Address",
      "Dropoff_Area",
      "Dropoff_City",
      "Unit_Price",
      "Number_of_Packages_in_Shipment",
      "Collection_Amount_for_delivered_Product",
      "Payment_Collection_Method",
      "Proof_Of_Delivery",
      "Shipment_Weight",
      "Shipment_Volume",
      "Pickup_Contact_Person_Name",
      "Pickup_Contact_Person_Number",
      "Pickup_Address",
      "Pickup_Area",
      "Pickup_City",
      "Comments"
    ],
    // manualRowMove: true,
    // manualColumnMove: true,
    // contextMenu: true,
    // filters: true,
    // dropdownMenu: true
  };

  dataset = [
    {
      Invoice_No: "ABCD1234",
      Product_Description: "XYZ",
      Receiver_Contact_Person_Name: "Jane Doe",
      Receiver_Contact_Number: "01700000001",
      Dropoff_Address: "DROPOFF_ADDRESS_1",
      Dropoff_Area: "Kawran Bazaar",
      Dropoff_City: "Dhaka",
      Unit_Price: 25,
      Number_of_Packages_in_Shipment: 2,
      Collection_Amount_for_delivered_Product: 50,
      Payment_Collection_Method: "PREPAID",
      Proof_Of_Delivery: "NONE",
      Shipment_Weight: 1,
      Shipment_Volume: 5,
      Pickup_Contact_Person_Name: "John Doe",
      Pickup_Contact_Person_Number: "01700000001",
      Pickup_Address: "PK_Address line",
      Pickup_Area: "Dhanmondi",
      Pickup_City: "Dhaka",
      Comments: "Comment"
    }
  ];
```