# send data from directive to controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

how can i send data from directive to controller ?
I've try that : http://jsfiddle.net/1xfvuotL/2/
But, i've got this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'methodToCall' of undefined
>   at formateData

My Directive:

```
search.directive('donutChartScope', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div style="position:absolute"></div>',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        title: '@',
        width: '@',
        height: '@',
        data: '=',
        objx: '='        
    },
    link: function (scope, element) {

        formateData = function (data, scope) {
            var categorie = data.momsCategorie;
            if (categorie == 'Hors Production') {
                var obj = 'HorsProd';
            }
            else if (categorie == 'Production') {
                var obj = 'Prod';
            }
            else if (categorie == 'Enseigne') {
                var obj = 'Enseigne';
            }
            var array = [];
            var i = 0;
            $.each(scope[obj].Ok, function(idx, elm) {
                array.push([scope[obj].Ok[i].Hostname, scope[obj].Ok[i].NMON, scope[obj].Ok[i].ATR]);
                i++;
            });
            scope.objx.methodToCall(array);
            console.log(array);
        }
```

[...]

```
scope.chart = Highcharts.chart(element[0],
                        {
                            chart: {
                                type: 'pie'
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: '',
                                style: {
                                    display: 'none'
                                }
                            },
                            subtitle: {
                                text: '',
                                style: {
                                    display: 'none'
                                }
                            },
                            plotOptions: {
                                pie: {
                                    shadow: false,
                                    center: ['50%', '50%'],
                                    point: {
                                        events: {
                                            click: function (event) {
                                                formateData(this, scope.data[0].drilldown.array);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
```

And my Controller:

```
search.controller('NmonCustomController', function (config, $http, $compile, $q, $scope, query, $mdDialog, $timeout, $rootScope) {

$scope.objx = {};
$scope.objx.methodToCall = function(i) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Thank you in advance for helping me and sorry for my great english

Comment: I don't see any error in provided `fiddle`

Comment: Yes, i have tried to change my code like this fiddle but its not my own. I have this error on my code: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'methodToCall' of undefined at formateData

Comment: Ok. can you show your html ?

Comment: `<div ng-controller="NmonCustomController" ng-init="init($ctrl)">
    
    <!--Graphique-->
    <div class="col-md-6" ng-model="dataNmon">
        <donut-chart-scope data="dataHighchart" objx="objx" style="margin-top: -50px; margin-left: -70px">      
        </donut-chart-scope>
    </div>
    
    <!--Datatable-->
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <datatable></datatable>
    </div>
    
</div>
    `

Comment: Everything seems to be Ok. your `controller` is above your `directive` definition right  ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing values from directive to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069816/passing-values-from-directive-to-controller)

Answer (score 0):

`scope.objx.methodToCall(array);`

scope variable in this line points to the argument passed to the `formateData` function, it does not refer to the scope variable in the link function.

Make sure you pass the correct scope variable in the `formateData` function call or change the variable names to a different one.